# Setting up keybinds in python on button click using PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to make it so where when I click on a button and use .clicked.connect() for a PyQt5 button that I can then listen for the next keystroke and to update the button text with that keystroke similar to how keybinds work in video games, actually exactly like that.

I have the rest of the script working, I just need to figure this part out.

Comment: usually left click is used to run function assigned to button - so using it to assign keystroke can be problem (if you still want to use left click to run this function). But if you use right click or some combination with key then you can always connect other function which will listen for keystrong and you may assign it to button.

Comment: Set a default `False` flag, then connect the clicked signal to a function that *toggles* that value, and override the `keyPressEvent` of your widget by checking if the flag is set (then eventually do something), and finally call the base implementation.

Comment: Does it have to be a button? Why can't you use [QKeySequenceEdit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequenceedit.html)?